# Как сохранить файл?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, javascript

Файл (пусть будет около 1Гб) в браузере пользователя нарезается при помощи функции `slice()` и отправляется в браузер партнера кусочками через сокет (часть кода пропущена):

```
reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        var data = evt.target.result;
        socket.emit('datatransfer', data, file, chunk);
    }
};
var blob = fileo.slice(start, stop + 1);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

Собственно как собрать этот файл из кусочков и сохранить на диск в браузере партнера посредством `JS`?

---

Пробовал просто кодировать его в `base64`, но если размер файла был достаточно большим, это вызывало зависание браузера.

Comment: А как зависит размер файла и кусок в base64?

Comment: @lampa,
> Пробовал просто кодировать его в base64, но если размер файла был достаточно большим, это вызывало зависание браузера.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe так я говорю о кодировании куска. И собственно вообще зачем кодировать? Интересно стало, надо попробовать своё сделать.

Comment: @lampa, так а как я получу файл из бинарной строки, которая записана в переменную в JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно попробовал написать передачу img файла.

На сервере всё просто

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')
app.listen(90);

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
    function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(data);
    });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // принимаем часть и отправляем
    socket.on('getChunk', function (chunk) {
        socket.emit('putChunk', { 'data': chunk });
    });
});
```

А вот с клиентом по**ался хорошенько. В общем суть такая:

кушаем файл кусочками, размером 1024 байт и отправляем на сервер:

```
function putFile(evt) {
    /**
     *
     */
    var file = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object
    var byteSize = 1024;

    for(var i=0; i < Math.ceil(file.size/byteSize); i++) {
        (function(i) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function(theFile) {
                var data = theFile.target.result;

                // отправляем часть
                socket.emit('getChunk', { 
                    'data': data, 
                    'no' : i,
                    'size': Math.ceil(file.size/byteSize),
                    'type': file.type
                });
            };

            var blob = file.slice(i * byteSize, (i + 1) * byteSize);
            reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

И собственно принимаем файл:

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    document.getElementById('files').disabled = false;

    var array = [];

    socket.on('putChunk', function (chunk) {

        array[chunk.data.no] = chunk.data.data;

        load_count++;

        if(load_count == chunk.data.size) {
            var byteString = array.join('');
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
            var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "data:"+chunk.data.type+";base64," + encode(ia);

            document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(img, null);
        }
    });
});
```

И полный кусок: http://pastebin.com/VXdtvJrw

Но вот неизвестно, как будет вести себя метод `join()` для огроменного массива. 
Еще есть такая штука, как [`BlobBuilder()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder) но я нипонял, почему она содержит метод `append()`, А `Blob()` - не содержит `=\`

Вот обновленный сервер, который отдает файл. Поправь только `Content-Type`

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')
app.listen(90);

var chunkContainer = [];

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
    function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});

        var chunkCounter = 0;

        setInterval(function() {
            if(chunkContainer.length > 0) {
                console.log(chunkContainer[0]);
                res.write(chunkContainer[0].data, "binary");

                chunkCounter++;

                if(chunkCounter == chunkContainer[0].size) {
                    res.end();
                }
                chunkContainer.splice(0, 1);
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // принимаем часть и отправляем
    socket.on('getChunk', function (chunk) {
        chunkContainer.push(chunk);
    });
});
```

Comment: @lampa, так это все и у меня есть, а попробуйте так передать картинку под 50Мб, браузер не сможет ее задекодить в base64, Safari вроде и пытается, а хром сразу падает.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe нуну, я понял вас. Я пытался blob сразу засунуть в FileReader, но не получается блин!.

Comment: @lampa, а не реально как-нибудь посылать куски так, чтобы браузер стандартным загрузчиком скачивал файл? (Ну там типа дополнять response).

Comment: @Niki-Timofe Конечно можно! Секундочку.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe обновил свой ответ. Последний пример.

Comment: @lampa, а как теперь сделать так, чтобы несколько клиентов могли качать с нескольки хостов?

Comment: @Niki-Timofe добавляйте каждому клиенту уникальный идентификатор.

Comment: @lampa, как?

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) — как собрать Blob из Base64.

Но, вам всё равно нужно будет на той стороне получить все куски и с вероятностью 99% бразер сложится.

P.S. `readAsBinaryString — deprecated`,  IE10+ его уже не поддерживает, но это не беда, можно Base64 преобразовать в `binaryString` при помощи atob.

Comment: @RubaXa, нету особого смысла собирать Blob из base64, браузер упадет еще на этапе кодирования в base.

Сдается мне, что можно как-то использовать FileSystem API и писать куски прямо в файл, который лежит в Sandbox'е браузера, но вот как это сделать средствами JS - не понимаю.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, и я вам о том же. FileWriter не умеет писать кусочки, он принимает только готовый Blob.